# Using Sphinx with PHP. Error with the "search" : "Search error: ."

Tags: php, sphinx

I'm testing Sphinx with PHP (tutorial : http://www.siteduzero.com/informatique/tutoriels/creer-un-moteur-de-recherche-avec-sphinx-et-php)

If I run "search" like this :

```
search -i news navigateur
```

I have the following error :

```
index 'news': search error: .
```

The indexer works fine :

> $ sudo indexer news
>   Sphinx 2.0.6-release (r3473) Copyright (c)
>   2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx
>   Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)
>
> using config file '/usr/share/php/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf'... 
>   indexing index 'news'...
>
> collected 57 docs, 0.7 MB sorted 0.1 Mhits, 100.0%
>
> done total 57 docs, 689264 bytes total 0.050 sec, 13684561 bytes/sec,
>   1131.67 docs/sec
>
> total 3 reads, 0.000 sec, 115.5 kb/call avg, 0.1 msec/call avg
>
> total 9 writes, 0.000 sec, 83.5 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg

And, testing with the API, the PHP code return nothing. Anybody already have this error ?

Here the config file :

> index news {
>
> ```
>     source = news
>     path   = /usr/share/php/sphinx/var/data/news
> ```
>
> }
>
> indexer {
>
> ```
>     mem_limit = 32M
> ```
>
> }
>
> searchd {
>
> ```
>     port      = 3312
>     log       = /usr/share/php/sphinx/var/log/searchd/searchd.log
>     query_log = /usr/share/php/sphinx/var/log/searchd/query.log
>     pid_file  = /usr/share/php/sphinx/var/log/searchd/searchd.pid
> ```
>
> }
>
> source news {
>
> ```
>     type                = mysql
>     sql_host            = localhost
>     sql_user            = root
>     sql_pass            =  
>     sql_db              = siteduzero_sphinx
>     sql_query_pre       = SET NAMES utf8
>     sql_query           = SELECT id\
>                                 , categorie\
>                                 , titre\
>                                 , contenu FROM news
>     sql_attr_uint       = categorie
>     sql_query_info      = SELECT titre FROM news WHERE id=$id }
> ```

Thanks.

Fabrice

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into the same problem. The root of evil in the last config parameter. This command will work correctly:

```
search -i news --noinfo navigateur
```

Or you can remove this string from config:

```
sql_query_info      = SELECT titre FROM news WHERE id=$id
```

If you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in the `search` utility.

The good news is the `search` utility, is just a testing tool, so its not critical. Its not actually used for anything other than testing.

As for your problem with the API, do you have the `searchd` daemon running?

Rather than just saying it returns 'nothing', you should use getLastError and getLastWarning to investigate why...